# Overloading MainForm constructor in C++Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I need to overload the constructor of the main form in a radStudio C++ application. In Delphi, this can be done through the keyword overload, but I can not find a way to do it in C++. The idea is to pass as a constructor argument a reference to a controller class in order to implement the MVC model. The problem is caused by the use of `Application-> CreateForm (..)`.

**Delphi example**

```
Constructor Create; overload;   // This constructor uses defaults

Constructor Create(name : string); overload;
```

Comment: You can go to `Project\Options\Application\Forms` and remove the automatically created forms if you want to manage the creation and destruction of them yourself.

Comment: Yes, I read the help of radStudio, but the problem is that CreateForm links the main form to the application and it is not advisable to do it in any other way. In Delphi there is a way to continue using CreateForm and overload the constructor. In C ++ I have not found in the documentation a form similar to the one used in Delphi.

Comment: If you remove all forms from the list of forms to be automatically created, Application->CreateForm() will not be called at all.

Answer (score 6):

There is no `overload` keyword in C++, nor is one needed.  Simply define your overloads as needed, the compiler is smart enough to detect overloads of the same name.

When you create a new TForm in C++Builder, the IDE already gives you a constructor that is compatible with `Application->CreateForm()`, eg:

```
class TMainForm : public TForm
{
...
public:
    __fastcall TMainForm(TComponent *Owner);
};
```

You can certainly define additional overloaded constructors however you want, eg:

```
class TMainForm : public TForm
{
...
public:
    __fastcall TMainForm(TComponent *Owner);
    __fastcall TMainForm(String name);
};
```

Just note that `CreateForm()` will not be able to call any overloaded constructors other than the default `TComponent*` constructor.  On the other hand, you should not be using `CreateForm()` to construct any TForm objects *other than* the `Application->MainForm`.  Instead, use the `new` operator to directly call the desired constructor, eg:

```
TMainForm *form = new TMainForm("My name here");
```

The same applies to Delphi, too.  Call `CreateForm()` only for the `MainForm`, and directly call other constructors as needed.  In fact, in Delphi, you generally *don't* need to `overload` constructors at all, you can simply define additional constructors using different names, eg:

```
TMainForm = class(TForm)
...
public
  constructor Create(Owner: TComponent); override;
  constructor CreateWithName(name: string);
end;
```

```
var
  form: TMainForm;
...
form := TMainForm.CreateWithName('My name here');
```

You can't do that in C++, as all constructors MUST have the same name as the class type.

If you find that the above doesn't work for you in C++, then don't overload the constructor at all.  Use a static class method instead, eg:

```
class TMainForm : public TForm
{
...
public:
    __fastcall TMainForm(TComponent *Owner);

    static TMainForm* __fastcall Create(String name)
    {
        TMainForm *form = new TMainForm(NULL);
        form->Name = name;
        return form;
    }   
};

...

TMainForm *form = TMainForm::Create("My name here");
```

Comment: Shouldn't the inherited constructor in Delphi be `override` too? How is this done in C++Builder?

Comment: Remy, many thanks for the solutions. This work fine, but I have another problem. After creating the form instance, I show the form through the Show () method. The problem is that after invoking Show () the form is closed.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis `override` is optional in C++11 and later, and doesn't exist pre-C++11.

Comment: @Remy: so in C++, that is not a problem.

Comment: @Jose the `Application->MainForm` is assigned by the first call to `CreateForm()` for a `TForm` object. If you do not assign a `MainForm`, then `Application->Run()` has nothing to do as it requires the `MainForm`, so it exits immediately, and then the app terminates when `_tWinMain()` exits. If you are not going to assign a `MainForm` then you need to use `ShowModal()` instead of `Show()` so that an active message loop is running while the Form is shown.